# How to pass one JSP to another JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am creating small web apps and I am facing the following problem. I have 2 JSPs and when I click the submit button, it repeats the value every time. What I want is that when I click on the submit button it should give only the corresponding value.

**index.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Class Video</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="second.jsp" method="post">
<table>
<% 

File f=new File("C:/Users/SHAKTI/Desktop/video"); 
File[] list=f.listFiles();
if(list.length!=0){
String s[]=new String[list.length];
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
s[i]=list[i].toString();
String fi=list[i].getName(); 
%> 
<tr><td><%=fi %></td>
<td><input type="text" name="file" value="<%=s[i] %>">
</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="play" value="Play"></td>

</tr>
<%}}
else{
%>
<tr>
<td>There is no any files in the database...</td>
</tr>
<% 
}
%>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**second.jsp**

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);

String id=request.getParameter("file");
   out.println("id = "+id);
    %>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit>
</form>
```

Comment: What value do you wish to pass from `first.jsp` to `second.jsp`, exactly?

Comment: BTW - 'jsp page' translates to 'Java server page page'.  I.E. the addition of 'page' is redundant (and looks silly).

Comment: i want to pass file name which i am retriveing

Answer (score 0):

First Jsp : Set Value in First Page

```
request.setAttribute("name",somevalue);
```

Second Jsp : Retrieve it in Second page

```
request.getAttribute("name")
```

Comment: my problem is  that i want only  desired value from that jsp  not all value

Comment: You wont get all values..only value that you set in "name" variable will be retrieved in second page.can you be more specific ?

Comment: when i run  first jsp i got 3 file name which are in my given folder

Comment: with 3 button  now here i want that in which button i click only name of that file shoul be print on browser.and here only  one same file name is printing whenever i click on any button.

Answer (score 0):

use `queryString`

```
URl: http://myaddress.com/xyz?name=jill&sex=f 
String someName = request.getParameter("name") ; 
String sex = request.getParameter("sex") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use session as described by javaBeginner.

you can also create a from on the fly and submit it.

write a function similar to this one and use it in your success:

```
function submitValues(url, params) {
var form = [ '<form method="POST" action="', url, '">' ];

for(var key in params) 
    form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');

form.push('</form>');

jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0].submit();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to pass a value from one jsp to another, Here are some

1) Adding that as a hidden variable and specifying the value

```
<input name="file" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

2)Adding it to the session and retrieving the session variable

```
session.setAttribute("file", value);
```

3)Passing that as a queryParameter

```
http://......one.jsp?file=""
```

Answer (score 0):

It is beacause you are iterating the loop here,

```
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
s[i]=list[i].toString();
String fi=list[i].getName();
```

so it will print the last element from the loop, to get the name u clicked on the button try  this .. Change this line as

```
<input type="text" name="file" value="<%=s[i] %>">
```

as,

```
<td><input type="button" class="btn" data-reqno=value="<%=s[i] %>" value="file name">
```

And handle it using jQuery like this , so that you can pass the value to next JSP,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

         $(".btn").click( 
             function() {
                 var selectedFileName = $(this).attr("data-reqno");

                 var urlToApprove = "/yourApp/req/filename?name=" + selectedFileName;

                               }
         );
    });
</script>
```

And also try to avoid Scriptlets in JSP , you can use JSTL or El for the same purpose .
Hope it helps !!

Comment: dear sir  what is the meaning of thisyourApp/req/filename?name="

Comment: @user3139341 It is the URL to pass the values to another JSP.

Comment: @user3139341 It is the url to redirect to the second page , the string after the "?" is the parameter you are passing. In your case it should be "/second.jsp?file=" + selectedFileName;

Answer (score 0):

there are many method to pass variable such as

```
session.setAttribute()
session.getAttribute
action "xxx.jsp?variable=1"
```